# Countable structure elementarily equivalent to $(\mathbb N; 0, S, < +, \cdot)$ via LS

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Here's the example from Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic", p152

(Begin example)

Consider the structure

$\mathfrak N = (\mathbb N; 0, S, < +, \cdot)$

We claim that there is a countable structure $\mathfrak M_0$, elementarily equivalent to $\mathfrak N$ (so that $\mathfrak M_0$ and $\mathfrak N$ satisfy exactly the same sentences) but not isomorphic to $\mathfrak N$.

Proof: We will construct $\mathfrak M_0$ by using the compactnss theorem. Expand the language by adding a new constant symbol $c$. Let

$\Sigma = \{0 \lt c, S0 \lt c, SS0 \lt c,...\}$

We claim that $\Sigma \cup Th \mathfrak N$ has a model. For consider a finite subset. That finite subset is true in

$\mathfrak N_k = (\mathbb N; 0, S, < +, \cdot, k)$

(where $k = c^{\mathfrak N_k}$) for some large $k$. So by the compactness theorem $\Sigma \cup Th \mathfrak N$ has a model.

By the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, $\Sigma \cup Th \mathfrak N$ has a countable model

$\mathfrak M = (|\mathfrak M|; 0^{\mathfrak M}, S^{\mathfrak M}, <^{\mathfrak M} +^{\mathfrak M}, \cdot^{\mathfrak M}, c^{\mathfrak M})$.

Let $\mathfrak M_0$ be the restriction of $\mathfrak M$ to the original language:

$\mathfrak M_0 = (|\mathfrak M|; 0^{\mathfrak M}, S^{\mathfrak M}, <^{\mathfrak M} +^{\mathfrak M}, \cdot^{\mathfrak M})$.

Since $\mathfrak M_0$ is a model of $Th \mathfrak N$, we have $\mathfrak M_0 \equiv \mathfrak N$:

$\vDash_\mathfrak N \sigma \implies \sigma \in Th \mathfrak N \implies \vDash_\mathfrak {M_0} \sigma$

$\nvDash_\mathfrak N \neg\sigma \implies \sigma \in Th \mathfrak N \implies \vDash_\mathfrak {M_0} \neg \sigma \implies \nvDash_\mathfrak {M_0} \sigma. $

We leave it to the reader to verify that $\mathfrak M_0$ is not isomorphic to $\mathfrak N$. ($|\mathfrak M_0|$ contains the "infinite" number $c^{\mathfrak M}$.)

(End of example)

My first question is that there seems to be a wff that is satisfiable in $\mathfrak M_0$, but not in $\mathfrak N$, and so the two stuctures aren't elementarily equivalent:

$\exists y \forall x  (x \lt y)$

Namely, in |$\mathfrak M_0$| there is the infinite number that is greater than all other numbers.

Assuming I am wrong with my counter-example, my second question is how would you prove that the two structures aren't isomorphic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You claim that $\exists y . \forall x . x < y$ is satisfied in $\mathfrak{M}_0$ but not in $\mathfrak{N}$. But this is not true.

In particular, we have $c < Sc$. Our new vocubulary contains not only the "standard" natural numbers plus $c$, but also many other terms like $Sc$, $c \cdot c$, and more. One can also show that $\exists! y (c = Sy)$, so "$c - 1$" (which isn't technically a term) exists as well.

Forcing a single nonstandard number to be in a model thus forces many others to be in the model as well.

To prove the two aren't isomorphic, simply consider the fact that the only homomorphism $\mathfrak{N} \to \mathfrak{M}_0$ sends $n$ to $(S^{\mathfrak{M}_0})^n(0^{\mathfrak{M}_0})$. Then it's easy to see that $c^{\mathfrak{M}_0}$ is not in the range of this homomorphism.

Comment: How would one prove there is only one homomorphism?

Comment: @Travis08 It’s easy to show by induction that the only homomorphism is the one I described.

Comment: Is this a good proof?

If there are two different homomorphisms g, h, then:

$g(0) = 0^{\mathfrak M_0} = h(0)$ by definition of homomorphism.

$g(n) = g(S^n(0)) = (S^{\mathfrak M_0})^n(g(0)) = (S^{\mathfrak M_0})^n 0^{\mathfrak M_0} = (S^{\mathfrak M_0})^n(h(0)) = h(S^n(0)) = h(n) $

Comment: @Travis08 Yes, that’s a good proof. Formally speaking, you’d have to prove it by induction, but you’ve basically got the idea there.

Comment: @MarkSaving How could one show that ∃!(=)?

Comment: @MattD First, note that $\forall x . (x = 0 \lor \exists! y (x = Sy)) \in Th(\mathfrak{N})$. Therefore, we have $c = 0 \lor \exists! y (c = Sy)$. But of course one of our axioms is $0 < c$, from which it follows that $c \neq 0$ (technically we'd have to use the fact that $\forall x (0 < x \to 0 \neq x) \in Th(\mathfrak{N})$, then instantiate this at $c$). So it follows that $\exists! y (c = Sy)$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Thanks for the quick reply. Is ∀.(=0∨∃!(=)) one of the Peano axioms? Your argument makes perfect sense from the initial assumption... I'm just curious where the initial assumption comes from.

Comment: @MattD It actually follows from induction. In the base case, we have $0 = 0$. In the inductive step, we have $Sk = Sk$. Definitely using a powerful tool for a rather trivial result.

Answer (score 2):

Your first concern certainly makes sense if you're evaluating elementary equivalence between $\mathfrak N$ and $\mathfrak M$ since Enderton here only considers an isolated nonstandard number $c$ and then adjoin $\Sigma$ with $Th\mathfrak N$. However, since you have below condition:

> Let $\mathfrak M_0$ be the restriction of $\mathfrak M$ to the original language

so $\mathfrak M_0$ share the same vocabulary with $\mathfrak N$ (your concerned sentence will never get modeled within $\mathfrak M_0$) thus there's no need for such cautious concern to arrive at $\mathfrak M_0 \equiv \mathfrak N$.

Regarding your second concern, isomorphic homomorphisms are structure preserving maps and here the structure in $\mathfrak N$ is obviously the "successor" structure inductively constructed via PA's axiomatization, so if there exists any such isomorphism then via induction schema the isolated $c^\mathfrak M$ cannot be included in the range of such isomorphism.