# Do non-standard interpretations actually model $\lnot\exists x\forall y(y\leq x)$?

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the typical way of putting together the non-standard model of true arithmetic. Now consider the following semantic calculation where $\mathcal{M_m^a}$ is a interpretation just like $\mathcal{M}$ except it adds $a$ to the language and assigns it to $m$. (Note this is the semantics from Burgess, Boolos, and Jeffrey's *Computability and Logic*.)

1. $\mathcal{M}\vDash\lnot\exists x\forall y(y\leq x)$ $\iff$ $\mathcal{M}\nvDash\exists x\forall y(y\leq x)$
2. $\mathcal{M}\nvDash\exists x\forall y(y\leq x)$ $\iff$ for some $m\in|\mathcal{M}|,\mathcal{M_m^a}\nvDash\forall y(y\leq c)$
3. for some $m\in|\mathcal{M}|,\mathcal{M_m^a}\nvDash\forall y(y\leq a)$ $\iff$ for all $n\in|\mathcal{M}|$ and some $m\in|\mathcal{M}|$,$\mathcal{M_{m,n}^{a,b}}\nvDash b\leq a$

Here's where I am confused. Isn't c, the nonstandard element, exactly an element in the universe that is greater than or equal to everything else? In other words, isn't the righthand side of 3 a contradiction?

I know I must be missing something. But I can't figure out what. Is it that there actually *is* a strict linear order among the nonstandard elements, it just "begins", so to speak, "after" all the natural numbers?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the nonstandard model of arithmetic we construct has only one nonstandard element. But that's not the case: besides the thing named by $c$, there will also be for example $c+1$.

Comment: Is there such a thing as 'the non-standard model of arithmetic'?

Comment: So how should we think of the relation between all the c's and the natural numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Countable structure elementarily equivalent to $(\mathbb N; 0, S, &lt; +, \cdot)$ via LS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302705/countable-structure-elementarily-equivalent-to-mathbb-n-0-s-cdot-v)